# Using CiviCRM for Coworking Check in tracking

Tags: civimember

One part of our nonprofit is running several co-working locations. We have members that can buy a part time membership that lets them use the facility 10 times a month.

We would need a way to have a member login page at the front of our locations where the member "checks-in." We'd want to display how many times that month they have checked in and how many more visits they have for the month.

While I'm asking, room reservations extensions/

Thanks,

Brad

Comment: always good to mention your cms

Answer (score 1):

To just track them, I would be using Activities, and if you are using Drupal you could put together a small block/form on login page where they would submit the Activity. Then use Views Aggregation to count their visits (and Views Calc to show how many remaining.

There is also the [civi booking extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civibooking) to check out. CiviCon video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBlVBaIAlRg)